# C language: error: ‘O_DIRECTORY’ undeclared and accessing files in directory and sub-directory(without using opendir())

Tags: c, file, operating-system, directory, system-calls

I want to loop through all the sub-directories and get all the files in the directory and sub-directories.
I only want to use the open() and read() system call to do so(not opendir() or is_dir)
bit I keep on getting an error

```
error: ‘O_DIRECTORY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

although I did imported the fcntl.

here is my code down below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
extern int errno; 

int main()
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open(".", O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY)) ==-1)
    {
        printf("error %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In addition how can use the read() system call to check if I'm reading a file or a sub-directory?
(as I mentioned I want to go also over the files in all the sub-directories)
I know is_dir does that but I'm looking for a way to do it without using it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you compile? If you do `-std=c11` it seems that *only* `O_DIRECTORY` is missing.

Comment: Also, the definition of `errno` is **wrong**, you **must** include `<errno.h>` for the correct thing! *"If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name errno, the behavior is undefined."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [holy scripture](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> The  `O_CLOEXEC`,  `O_DIRECTORY`,  and `O_NOFOLLOW` flags are not
>          specified   in   POSIX.1-2001,   but   are   specified   in
>          POSIX.1-2008.  Since glibc 2.12, one can obtain their definitions by defining either  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`  with  a  value
>          greater  than  or  equal to `200809L` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` with a
>          value greater than or equal to `700`.  In glibc 2.11 and earlier, one obtains the definitions by defining `_GNU_SOURCE`.

---

Try compiling with `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` or add a `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before including any headers.